# How to use space key to separate new rows and columns while using Scanner in java

Tags: java, multidimensional-array

I am making a Reversi game like this:

```
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Scanner;
public class test{

    public static Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);

    public static void main(String[] args) {

    System.out.print("Please enter the board size (4 or above and even number) : ");
    int num = sc.nextInt();
    int rows = num; // Number of rows 
    int cols = num; // Number of columns 
    if (num % 2 == 1 || num < 4) {
        System.out.println("Error - input number should be 4 or above and even number.");
    } else {
        int[][] reversigame = new int[rows][cols];
        for (int i = 0; i < rows; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < cols; j++) {
                System.out.print(reversigame[i][j] + " ");
            }
            reversigame[num - num / 2][num - num / 2] = 1;
            reversigame[(num - num / 2) - 1][(num - num / 2) - 1] = 1;
            reversigame[(num - num / 2)][(num - num / 2) - 1] = 2;
            reversigame[(num - num / 2) - 1][(num - num / 2)] = 2;
            System.out.println();
        }
```

but I want to use the space key to separate new rows and columns while using Scanner, like this:

```
System.out.print("Please enter the position of '1' (row col): ");
int bcp = sc.nextInt();//bcp=black chess place
int b = 1;//black chess = 1
String[] digits = String.valueOf(bcp).split(" ");
```

but it can't be changed to the Row and columns while I'm doing next step:

```
if (bcp > 5 || bcp < 0) {/*Control variables between 0 and 5*/
System.out.println("Error - input number should be 0 to 5!");

            }
            for (; reversigame[bcp  + 1][bcp] == 2 || reversigame[bcp][bcp + 1] == 2 || reversigame[bcp - 1][bcp] == 2 || reversigame[bcp][bcp + 1] == 2;) {/*Check the black chess is or is't near the white chess*/
                reversigame[bcp][bcp] = b;
                System.out.println(Arrays.deepToString(reversigame));
                if (reversigame[bcp + 1][bcp] != 2 || reversigame[bcp][bcp+ 1] != 2 || reversigame[bcp - 1][bcp] != 2 || reversigame[bcp][bcp + 1] != 2) {
                    System.out.println("Error - invalid move");
                    break;
                }
            }
```

So, how should I add rows and columns in one sentence while using the space key to separate them?

Answer (score 2):

You can just separate numbers with space and read two ints in a sequence:

```java
Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
int a = scanner.nextInt();
int b = scanner.nextInt();
System.out.println("result = " + (a + b));
```

with output like:

```
2 5
result = 7
```

Answer (score 0):

> *"... I want to use the space key to separate new rows and columns while using Scanner ..."*

Just call *nextInt* twice.

```java
int[] digits = { sc.nextInt(), sc.nextInt() };
```

If you need *String* values, use the *[next](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/21/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Scanner.html#next())* method.

```java
String[] digits = { sc.next(), sc.next() };
```

Alternately, use the *[nextLine](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/21/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Scanner.html#nextLine())* method, and then *split* on a *space* character.

```java
String[] digits = sc.nextLine().split(" +");
```

Answer (score 0):

All you need is use `scan.nextInt()` twice.

```java
public class Reversi {

    private static final int WHITE = 1;
    private static final int BLACK = 2;

    private static final int ROW = 0;
    private static final int COL = 1;

    public static void main(String... args) {
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
        int size = readBoardSize(scan);
        int[][] board = new int[size][size];
        int nextMove = WHITE;

        printBoard(board);

        while (true) {
            int[] point = readNextMove(scan, nextMove, size);
            int row = point[ROW];
            int col = point[COL];
            board[row][col] = nextMove;
            printBoard(board);
            nextMove = nextMove == WHITE ? BLACK : WHITE;
        }
    }

    private static void printBoard(int[][] board) {
        for (int row = 0; row < board.length; row++) {
            for (int col = 0; col < board[row].length; col++) {
                if (col > 0)
                    System.out.print(' ');
                System.out.print(board[row][col]);
            }

            System.out.println();
        }

    }

    private static int readBoardSize(Scanner scan) {
        final int min = 4;
        System.out.format("Please enter the board size (%d or above and even number): ", min);

        int num = scan.nextInt();

        if (num < min || num % 2 == 1) {
            System.err.format("Input number should be %d or above and even number.\n", min);
            throw new RuntimeException();
        }

        return num;
    }

    private static int[] readNextMove(Scanner scan, int nextMove, int size) {
        final int min = 0;

        System.out.format("Please enter the position of '%d' (row col): ", nextMove);
        int row = scan.nextInt();
        int col = scan.nextInt();

        if (row < min || row >= size || col < min || col >= size) {
            System.err.format("Input number should be between %d and %d.\n", min, size);
            throw new RuntimeException();
        }

        int[] point = new int[2];
        point[ROW] = row;
        point[COL] = col;

        return point;
    }
}
```